# InDesign script change substring style in textframe

Tags: html, css, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I want to build an InDesign script which when you import html tags such as bold and italics, those words are converted to bold or italics.

e.g.

`I really like <strong>walking to the park</strong> and eating icecream` would be:

I really like **walking to the park** and eating icecream.

However, In my textframe I can only get a whole paragraph to pick up a style and not individual words or phrases.

In the example below, I would want to apply a bold style to the secondPhrase variable (I have no problem stripping out the tags etc - just want to know how I can apply a style to JUST the secondPhrase

```
with (myElement) {

    // Apply basic text style
    applyParagraphStyle(myDoc.paragraphStyles.item("DefaultText"));

    var firstPhrase = "I really like";
    var secondPhrase = " walking to the park";  
    var thirdPhrase = " and eating icecream";

    contents = firstLine + secondLine + thirdPhrase;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the code below should do the trick. The `insertionPoint` acts just like the cursor in InDesign. If you keep grabbing the last `insertionPoint` you can change it's style while you are adding text.

```
var doc = app.documents.add();

var frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames.add({
   geometricBounds: [6, 6, 40, 40]
});

var bold = doc.characterStyles.add({ name: "Bold", fontStyle: "Bold" });
var none = doc.characterStyles.itemByName("[None]");

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(none);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = "I really like";

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(bold);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = " walking to the park";

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(none);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = " and eating icecream";
```

Comment: This not working for me. instead of making bold it is highlighting that text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a DRY-er take on Josh's solution -- insertion points are the way to go. If you need to manipulate, mirror, or are working with dynamic JSON content / want to separate out your text, you'll need to run it through a loop, and simply assign your chunks of text as objects. This makes it much easier to swap out text and make use of some things like `Array.prototype.reverse()`, which I needed to use in my case.

Here's my take on it:

```
// Basic Setup
var doc = app.documents.add();
var myPage = doc.pages.item(0); // Arbitrary page

// Character-Styles
var bold = doc.characterStyles.add({ name: "Bold", fontStyle: "Bold" });
var none = doc.characterStyles.itemByName("[None]");

// My String as an Array of Objects (Basic JSON format)
var myStringsAndStyles = [
  {
    contents: "I really like",
    characterStyle: none
  },
  {
    contents: " walking to the park ",
    characterStyle: bold
  },
  {
    contents: "and eating ice cream.",
    characterStyle: none
  }
];

// Do stuff
with ( myPage) {

  var myTextFrame = textFrames.add({
    geometricBounds: [6, 6, 40, 40] // Arbitrary coords
  });

  with ( myTextFrame.insertionPoints ) {
    for ( var i = 0, arrlength = myStringsAndStyles.length; i < arrlength; i++ ) {
      lastItem().properties = {
        contents: myStringsAndStyles[i].contents,
        appliedCharacterStyle: myStringsAndStyles[i].characterStyle
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Ta da!